# Bug with useState / useEffect react spread operator

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am having an issue where I am setting state with a spread operator but the function call in `useEffect` only ever sets the last value pulled from the API into state.

```
// get all events to display on load
const getEvents = () => {
    console.log(props.id);
    axios.get(API.EVENTS.ROOT + props.id).then(
        res => {
            const data = res.data;
            setEvent(data);
            console.log(data);
            // event start and end dates
            setStart(new Date(data.start));
            setEnd(new Date(data.finish));
            // breakout dates
            for (let i = 0; i < data.breakouts.length; i++) {
                console.log(data.breakouts[i].start);
                data.breakouts[i].start = new Date(data.breakouts[i].start);
                data.breakouts[i].end = new Date(data.breakouts[i].end);
                console.log(data.breakouts[i].name, "test" + data.breakouts[i].start);
                // set date picker initial value 
                setFields({
                    ...fields,
                    [data.breakouts[i].name]: data.breakouts[i].start
                })
                console.log(fields);
            }

            setBreakoutRow(data.breakouts);
            console.log(breakoutRow);

        }
    ).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
}
// get events on load
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props);
    getEvents();
}, []);
```

I add the fields state variable or the `getEvents` function as a dependency it does update the `state` of fields for all values but it results in an infinite loop of death. This is giving me blank dates in mapped rows for all but the last.

Another item of note is that after the page loads the fields object can be updated no problem through a function call, as so:

```
const handleDateChange = (dateName, dateValue) => {
        console.log(dateName, dateValue);
        setFields({
            ...fields,
            [dateName]: dateValue
        })
        console.log(fields);
    }
```

This leads me to believe there is something wrong with my `useEffect` hook but I am not sure where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reason is how you're accessing *previous* value to add new element:

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.breakouts.length; i++) {
  data.breakouts[i].start = new Date(data.breakouts[i].start);
  setFields({
    ...fields,
    [data.breakouts[i].name]: data.breakouts[i].start
  })
}
```

since `fields` will be updated only on next render, you are adding single element(but each loop it's different element) to the array.

The same would be without hooks/react:

```
const start = [];
for(let i = 0; i< 5; i++) console.log([...start, i]);
```

This will never output `[0,1,2,3,4]`.

What can you do.

### Option 1. Collect data in interm variable:

```
const temp = {};
for (let i = 0; i < data.breakouts.length; i++) {
  data.breakouts[i].start = new Date(data.breakouts[i].start);
  data.breakouts[i].end = new Date(data.breakouts[i].end);
  temp[data.breakouts[i].name] = data.breakouts[i].start
}
setFields({
  ...fields,
  ...temp
});
```

### Option 2. Use functional version of setter as an accumulator:

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.breakouts.length; i++) {
  data.breakouts[i].start = new Date(data.breakouts[i].start);
  setFields(({fields: prevFields}) => ({
    ...prevFields,
    [data.breakouts[i].name]: data.breakouts[i].start
  }))
}
```

I'd prefer first option for 2 reasons:

1. it would be better finally move data transform closer to call point, so instead of `axios.get` there would be some `API.getMeaningfullThings` returning structure you need; so it's easier to refactor
2. maybe slighter more code shows better what's going on(it's just a transforming, not a filtering or any React-specific thing)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you have problem with `setState` from first example. Te reason is that you are calling `setState` inside of a loop, and you are trying to spread the old state, but the state doesn't get set before your loop is done, so you have to accumulate everything you want to put into your state inside the loop and set it at the end.